# Section of a line bundle after tensoring with ideal sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

Let $ L$ be a line bundle on a smooth complex projective curve $X$ with genus $ g \geq 2$ such that $  L$ is not base point free. Let $I_Z$ be the ideal sheaf of its base locus.

**Questions**:

- In this situation can we say that  $(I)$ $ L \otimes I_Z$ is a line bundle?
- And
  $(II)$ $ h^0( L)= h^0( L \otimes I_Z)$?

**What I tried so far:**
If we rewrite $L(-Z)=L \otimes \mathcal O(-Z)= L \otimes I_Z$ , then infact one has $h^0(L) \leq h^0(L(-Z))$ (why?). Now if we denote the canonical map induced by the line bundle by:

$\phi : X \to \mathbb P((H^0(X,L))^* =\mathbb P^r$. Then one has the following isomorphisms :

$(i)$ $\phi^{*}(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^r}(1)) \cong L(-Z)$ and $(ii)$$H^0(\mathbb P^r, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^r}(1)) \cong H^0(X,L)$

From $(i)$ it follows that $L(-Z)$ is a line bundle( Perhaps this also because it's the tensor product of two line bundles given by $L$ and $\mathcal O(-Z)$)

One can use $(i)$, $(ii)$ and projection formula to show $ h^0( L)= h^0( L \otimes I_Z)$.

Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your line bundle L has base points, so how are you getting $ \phi $ on all of $ X $? That map is only defined on the open set which is the complement of the set of base points.

Comment: @Cranium Clamp, yes it's a rational map...but does that affect the rest of the arguments?

Comment: Right, it is just a rational map. So how are you pulling back $ O(1) $ to a line bundle on X? You'll get a line bundle only on an open subset, apriori.

Comment: @Cranium Clamp, these I'm not so sure. These isomorphisms are taken from the book Geometry of Algebraic curves first chapter (volume 1)

Comment: I would look at it this way: The fact that $ L \otimes I_Z $ is a line bundle is clear. Then we have an inclusion of sheaves $ L \otimes I_Z \rightarrow L $. This gives an injective map on global sections. This map is also surjective for the following reason: Suppose $ D $ is a Cartier divisor associated to $ L $. For any $ f \in H^0(X,L) $, $ div(f) + D \ge 0 $ but $ Z $ is the divisor of base points which means $ div(f) + D \ge Z $, i.e. $ f \in H^0(X, L \otimes I_Z) $ as well.